# Find and replace multi line file content in files

Tags: file, replace, sed, newline, multiline

What I want to do is:

```
find some_files -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "s/`cat old`/`cat new`/g" {} \;
```

with *old* and *new* containing newline characters and slashes and other special characters, which prevent sed from parsing correctly.

I have read about how to escape newline characters with sed, and the command *tr*, the command *printf '%q'*, but I can't make these work properly, maybe because I don't fully understand their function. Additionally, I don't know which special characters I still have to escape for sed to work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As it stands, for each html file, if it finds the entire contents of file old, it replaces it with the entire content of file new.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what are you trying to edit

Comment: Daniel Landau Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. The problem is that those files contain special characters (like slashes) that are interpreted by sed and I would like to escape them out.

Comment: For more precision, the error I get when executing the above command is "unterminated `s' command".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but if the old file contains newlines, you're probably going to run into trouble. That is because sed works by applying the commands on each line, so trying to match a line with a pattern that represents multiple lines will not work unless you load more lines explicitly.

My suggestion would be to load the whole file into sed's "buffer" before applying the substitute command. Then, you'd have to make sure that old and new are escaped correctly. Also, what could become more confusing is that escaping for the old file (the pattern) must be different than for the new file (the replacement).

Let's start by escaping the new file into a "new.tmp" file. For clarity, we'll create a sed script called "escape_new.sed":

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# Commas used as separators
s,\\,\\\\,g
s,$,\\,g
s,[/&],\\&,g
$ a/
```

Then run it: `sed -f escape_new.sed new > new.tmp`

There are three commands we use to escape:

1. Backslashes should be preceded by another backslash
2. Newlines should be preceded by a backslash (we do this by adding a backslash before the end of the line).
3. Ampersands and slashes should be preceded by a backslash (notice that the & at the replacement text is actually an operator that contains the match, therefore if it matches the slash it contains the slash, and if it matches the ampersand, it contains the ampersand).
4. On the last line (refered to with the "$" symbol), we append (through the "a" command) a slash. This is the closing slash for the substitute command we will be using later. We have to put it here because the backticks will remove any extra newlines at the end of the input, and that can cause problems (like for example a backslash used for quoting a newline actually quoting the terminating slash).

Now let's escape the old file. As above, we'll create an "escape_old.sed" script. Before we do it though, we need to load the whole file into the pattern space (sed's internal buffer) so we can replace newline characters. We can do that with the following commands:

```
: a
$! {
    N
    b a
}
```

The first command creates a label called "a". The second command ("{") actually starts a group of commands. The magic here is the "$!" address prefix. That prefix tells it to run the commands only if the last input line that was read wasn't the last line of the input ("$" means last line of the input and "!" means not). The first command in the group appends the next line from the input into the pattern space. If this "N" command is executed in the last line, it terminates the script, so we must be careful to not execute it on the last line. The second command in the group is a branch command, "b", which will "jump" back to the "a" label. The magic is the "$!" address prefix we have before the command. The closing bracket closes the group. This group, with its respective address prefix, allows us to loop through all of the lines, concatanting them together, and stop after the last line, allowing any further commands to be executed. We then have the final script:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

: a
$! {
    N
    b a
}

s,\\,\\\\,g
s,\n,\\n,g
s,[][/^$.],\\&,g
```

As above, we need to escape the special characters. In this case an actual newline is now escaped as a backslash followed by the letter n. In the last command, there are more characters that need to be prefixed by a backslash. Notice that to match a closing square-bracket, it needs to be the first character inside the square-brackets, to prevent sed from interpreting it as the closing character for our list of characters to match. Therefore, the characters that are listed in order between the square brackets are `][/^$.` .

And again, we execute it with: `sed -f escape_new.sed old > old.tmp`

Now we can use these escaped files in the sed command, but again we must load all of the lines into pattern space. Using the same commands as before, but placing them into a single line we have the compact form: `:a;$!{N;ba}`: which we can now use in the final expression (without the closing slash character that is now on the new.tmp file):

```
find some_files -name '*.html' -exec sed -e ":a;\$!{N;ba};s/`cat old.tmp`/`cat new.tmp`g" -i {} \;
```

And hopefully it will work =)

Notice that we have escaped the `$` symbol with a backslash, otherwise the shell will think that we are trying to access the  `$!` variable (result of the last asynchronous command executed).

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I wanted to do, and your answer is very well explained. :)

Comment: Now it *almost* works. I have done some tests with different samples of files. It doesn't work with multiline files but it does work when I enter multiline text in the standard input. The cat command seems to terminate the command line when it finds a newline character.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a not working combination of inputs, please? It could help finding the problem. Thanks =)

Comment: I must have been wrong, the problem is not the cat command. Here is what I just tried: I created an HTML file containing: "beginning" on the first line, "oldline1" on the second line, "oldline2" on the third line and then some other text. I also created a file "old" containing "oldline1" on the first line and "oldline2" on the second, and a file "new" containing "newline1" on the first line and "newline2" on the second. Then I ran your scripts to generate old.tmp and new.tmp. I finally ran the last command line. No error when executing but the HTML file wasn't changed.

Comment: But I forgot to mention that I had to remove the backslash at the end of the last line of new.tmp. Before I did that, I had an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unterminated `s' command" (probably because the backslash escaped the OEF). Then I made another test with only "oldline1" in old.tmp, and it correctly replaced "oldline1" with the two lines "newline1" and "newline2" in my HTML file. So there must be a problem catching '\n'.

Comment: Ok. From your example I've found a problem. Apparently, the backticks remove any extra newlines from the input. One workaround for this is to add the line `$a/` to the escape_new.sed script, and remove the `/` before the g in the final command. I'll edit the post. See if it works for you. If not, notify me and we'll see if there's something else to it. When you said, "and there some other text" for the HTML file, did you mean on the same third line, or as a fourth line?

Comment: I meant as a fourth line. I have made other tests, manually changing the content of old.tmp and checking if a change is made in the HTML file. Here are some interesting results: If the content of old.tmp is "oldline1\noldline2" or "\noldline2" or "oldline1\n", it fails. If it is "oldline2\n", it works. If it is "\noldline", only the first occurrence is replaced.

Comment: Hi, I think I've found the problem. We need to quote the '$' symbol on the last command, otherwise bash will replace it with the result of the previous asynchronous command (ie. the value of the `$!` variable). Just doing `\$!ba` fixed it for me. I'll re-edit the post =)

Comment: I just found another problem. The "escape_old" script doesn't seem to escape anything if the "old" file is only one line. Don't know why.

Comment: Found the problem. Apparetly the 'N' command will quit the script if you try to read past the last line. Sorry, I didn't know about this behaviour =( I'll edit the post to fix it, the solution is to just make sure that it doesn't run on the last line.